# how to decode json data in php file

Tags: php, android

I want to decode json data which come from android like

```
["{\"User_Registartion_Details\":{\"fullname\":\"ssss\",\"emailid\":\"sumitbwm@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"8796485577\",\"location\":\"pune\"}}"]
```

how to do it....get data from json and save in my sql db suing php script trying but in my sql show null values. This my php code which get json data and decode then save in database.I tried but but store null values(blank).
Data get from android page in json format and decode in php script the save in db..anyboday have idea about this please help..i new in android/php.
This my php code which get json data and decode then save in database

```
    <?php

    // Include confi.php
    include_once('conection.php');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] == "application/json")
    {

        $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $array = json_decode($request,true);
        $name = $array['fullname'];
        $email = $array['emailid'] ;
        $mobileno = $array['mobile'] ;
        $location = $array['location'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO  usertable (`fullname`, `emailid`, `mobile`, `location`) VALUES ('$array[name]', '$array[email]', '$array[mobileno]', '$array[location]')";
        $qur = mysql_query($sql);
        if($qur)
        {
            $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
        }
        else
        {
            $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
        }
    }else
    {
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
    }

    @mysql_close($conn);

    /* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON Encoding and Decoding in PHP is done using the `json_encode` and `json_decode``functions.

```
// To encode
$encodes = json_encode($json);

// To decode 
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);

// To see which variables are inside your decoded json
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($decoded);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

#### Edit

Your problem is that your json string is incorrect. I had to decode it twice to make it work.

```
// Incorrect json string
$json = '["{\"User_Registartion_Details\":{\"fullname\":\"ssss\",\"emailid\":\"sumitbwm@g‌​mail.com\",\"mobile\":\"8796485577\",\"location\":\"pune\"}}"]';

// Correct Json string
$json = '{"User_Registartion_Details":{"fullname":"ssss","emailid":"sumitbwm@gâ€Œâ€‹mail.com","mobile":"8796485577","location":"pune"}}';

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(json_decode($json));

object(stdClass)#25 (1) {
  ["User_Registartion_Details"]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (4) {
    ["fullname"]=>
    string(4) "ssss"
    ["emailid"]=>
    string(24) "sumitbwm@gâ€Œâ€‹mail.com"
    ["mobile"]=>
    string(10) "8796485577"
    ["location"]=>
    string(4) "pune"
  }
}
```

You can access your request by looking at the `$_POST` variable

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

Display it using `var_dump($_POST);`

#### Example

```
// Your android application sends a request
// This request is part of the HTTP protocol
// It is either a POST, GET, PUT or DELETE request

// PHP handles PUT and DELETE as a POST request
// The request data will be stored in the $_POST varaible and the $_REQUEST variable
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Use a var_dump to learn what key holds the json data

    var_dump($_POST);

    // let's say its in $_POST['json']
    $json = $_POST['json'];

    var_dump(json_decode($json));
}
```

#### Resources

- [json_encode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [json_decode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: but sir i trying store blank data in db...$decoded = json_decode($json) what is the values of json

Comment: how to server know which vaiable store json array...see my php code

Comment: suppose my data this is  ["{\"User_Registartion_Details\":{\"fullname\":\"ssss\",\"emailid\":\"sumitbwm@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"8796485577\",\"location\":\"pune\"}}"] then how to decode this in php script

Comment: please sir i need your suggestion please help

Comment: but sir its valid json array

Comment: my problem is that suppose i define                                               $request = "?"(how to know which variable(json object) contain json data)
 $array = json_decode($request,true);
 $name = $array['fullname'];  sorry but i justt confused

Comment: Look again. I added two strings. Your string and the valid string.

Comment: sir i'm not directly pass json string json data coming from android client side.....$json="?"

Comment: @sumitkumar Using `var_dump()` on the decoded string like i showed.

Comment: but sir $json variable how to get data from request....in above you directly pass json string..but in my case json string coming from request....i confused

Comment: Ahhhh.. I think i understand. You will need to take a look at the `$_POST` variable. That holds the posted data.

Comment: please can define that steps in 2-5 lines please....i dont have 2 much knowlege of php...

Comment: please sir it warm request to u

Comment: No problem! :) You can click the accept button to the left of my answer.

Comment: $json = $_POST['json'] inside post[json] json is variable or jsonobject

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and post your results.